# Is verb + と同じくらい grammatical

Tags: grammar, particle-と, comparative-constructions

> ロンがハリーに興味を**持ったと同じぐらい**、ハリーもロンに関心を持った。
> Harry was interested in Ron just as much as Ron was interested in Harry.

Is it grammatical to have と同じぐらい after a verb? I would have expected to see a nominaliser (の) inserted. Presumably this is the usual と that comes with 同じ, which marks the thing to be compared against, rather than either of the と which I would expect to see with a verb (quote/conditional).

Comment: I would have expected to see の there, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grammatically correct or not, searching on [shonagon](https://clrd.ninjal.ac.jp/bccwj/) gives a few result without の. Searching with の gives about x2 results, so you can be assured that verb + の + と同じくらい is more common. In the below samples, の can always be inserted.

> ひとりでいることは、自分の身体の半分がもぎ取られ**たと**同じくらいの痛みがあるのです - 唯川恵 彼女は恋を我慢できない 1995
>
> 冬に戻っ**たと**同じくらい寒かったです。- Yahooブログ
>
> 私はきっと海賊が宝の山を発見し**たと**同じくらいに喜んだのだと思います - 元加津子 たんぽぽの仲間たち 1996

---

There may be several explanations though I'm not sure if any of them is valid. The absence of の is a kind of things native speakers would just pass without much thinking.

1. It is an error by confusion with other constructions. For example, there's も同然 which I think comes more often without の.

- 犯罪を犯したも同然 - の can be inserted, but less frequently.

2. の is just omitted from のと同じくらい
3. と plays the double role of nominalizer and comparison particle. Technically it should be とと, which is of course impossible and contracted.